# Pythonic way to set.add() or set.update() with a return for passing as an arg?

Tags: python, set

In Python, naturally set.add() and set.update() do not return the modified set. However, if I want to pass a modified version of an existing set as an arg in say a recursive function it seems I have to create a temporary set: The following seems cumbersome.

```
temp_set = set([an_element])
temp_set.update(an_existing_set)
foo(temp_set)
```

Is there no single line trick for this? Adding *and* returning in a single statement?
Note I specifically do not want to modify the existing set in place.

```
foo(set([an_element].addAndReturn(an_existing_set))
```

I suppose the answer might just be "pass the new elem/set along with the old and combine them in place after the recursive call", but I am unsatisfied with this limitation.

Comment: Unless you need the added functionality of the `.update()` method, why not simply create a union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo(an_existing_set | {an_element})
```

Just use the set union operator.

There's also a method form, `union`:

```
foo(an_existing_set.union({an_element}))
```

Comment: That creates a new set, it doesn't modify the existing set.

Comment: @Barmar: Creating a new set is exactly what the question asks for. "Note I specifically do not want to modify the existing set in place."

Comment: Then the question isn't clear, because that's exactly what `.update()` does.

Comment: @Barmar: `update` modifies the original set. `union` is the one that makes a new set.

Comment: @Barmar Their `.update()` modifies the new temp set, not the existing set.

Comment: Now I understand the question, this is the correct answer.

Comment: If you edit the answer (e.g. to show how to call `.union()`), I can remove my erroneous downvote.

Comment: Ah, perfect. This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. Yes, the whole idea is to eliminate lines of code and not store extra garbage in each stack frame. I knew there had to be a simple Pythonic way of doing it.